# JavaScript parsing urlencoded query parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a strange problem parsing a URL encoded query string parameter in JavaScript.

```
function getUrlVars() {

    var vars = [], hash;
    alert(window.location.href);
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href).indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    alert(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

URL: http://domain/approveFile/ApproveFile.aspx?id=DZj9aEoyZ2I%3d

The value `"DZj9aEoyZ2I="` is a base64 URL encoded value, but it does not parse correctly; it ignores `"%3d"`. Please suggest a solution?

Comment: First, use `window.location.search.slice(1)` instead of trying to parse out this part of the URL yourself. Secondly, you're decoding the parts before splitting on `=`, which means `%3d` is being treated like a key-value seperator, ending up in `hash[2]` inside the loop. Finally, I'm pretty sure that instead of splitting on `"&"` you should be splitting on `/&(?!amp;)/` i.e. `&`s that aren't an `&amp;`

Comment: (ran out of time to edit) Actually the last point about `&` is wrong, it is encoded to `%26`, not `&foo;`s which are _HTML entities_, sorry

Comment: @PaulS.A correct URL should not have the `&` encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're decoding the parts before splitting on `=`, which means `%3d` is being treated like a *key-value separator*, ending up in `hash[2]` inside the loop. This seems to be undesired behaviour, so the fix is to `decodeURIComponent` after all the `.split`s

---

Tried implementing `foo[]` as list functionality similar to what you find in *php*, posting for prosperity..

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var $_GET = Object.create(null), // for..in safe
        pairs = window.location.search.slice(1).split('&'),
        pair,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
        pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        if (pair[0].slice(-2) === '[]') {
            pair[0] = pair[0].slice(0, -2);
            pair[0] = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
            if (pair[1]) pair[1] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]); // don't assume this
            if (!(pair[0] in $_GET))
                $_GET[pair[0]] = [];
            else if (!Array.isArray($_GET[pair[0]]))
                $_GET[pair[0]] = [$_GET[pair[0]]];
            $_GET[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
        } else {
            pair[0] = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
            if (pair[1]) pair[1] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]); // don't assume this
            $_GET[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }
    }
    return $_GET;
}
```

Use on a *URL* with *search `?foo=bar%3d&baz[]=fizz&baz[]=buzz`* will give

```
getUrlVars(); // {"foo": "bar=", "baz": ["fizz", "buzz"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode the value only after you extract it;

```
function getUrlVars() {

    var vars = {}, hash; url = 'http://domain/approveFile/ApproveFile.aspx?id=DZj9aEoyZ2I%3d';
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars[hash[0]] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
    }
    return vars;
}
```

This gives you `Object {id: "DZj9aEoyZ2I="}`.

Comment: now one strange problem if url= location.href then javascript is reading as 
"DZj9aEoyZ2I=" instead of DZj9aEoyZ2I%3d  any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays in 2016 if you're using ES6:

```
const getUrlParams = (search) => {
    let hashes = search.slice(search.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')
    let params = {}
    hashes.map(hash => {
        let [key, val] = hash.split('=')
        params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val)
    })

    return params
}

console.log(getUrlParams(window.location.search))
```